# Keep ios6 disclosure indicator apparence in ios7

Tags: ios6, uitableview, ios7, indicator, disclosure

The iOS Disclosure Indicator changed appearance in ios7; it's now a faded grey.
Unfortunately, my app has a lot of pages (more than 100) with different sections and background colors. On ios6, there is no problem, but on ios7 the new disclosure indicator is not visible on the background of some sections.

I need a solution, because I don't have the time to change more than 100 page background, and even if I did, if the color disclosure indicator looks okay in ios7, it's not in ios6, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `tintColor` of the table view. This will color the disclosure indicator on the cells.

Note that the `tintColor` property is only available under iOS 7 so code it properly:

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    self.tableView.tintColor = ... // the desired color
}
```

Comment: are you sure? This doesn't work for me. Tried setting it in the Storyboard and in ViewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Will it be possible for you to create custom images for ios7, and set the accessoryView of the problem cells in a method such as the data source 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' like below?

```
if(UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion.floatValue >= 7)
{

    UIImageView* customDisclosureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:normalImage];
    customDisclosureImageView.highlightedImage = selectedImage;
    cell.accessoryView = customDisclosureImageView;
}
```